# objective-c getters/setters & variable/property declarations--an easier way?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hopefully this is an easy one.

I'm coding in objective-c and i'm wondering if there are any tools/tricks (anything) that you use for this annoyance (see below).

Is there an easier way to declare variable/properties within the header and implementation files?

e.g., I'm not a big fan of typing this in the header:

```
NSString *commercial_name;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *commercial_name
```

and then typing

```
@synthesize commercial_name
```

in the implementation

it's quite tedious when all 3 things are needed (or when I have to delete all 3) and I'm wondering if there's a plugin (or something) where you can simply say, I'm going to have a variable called **foo** of type **bar** and I want getter & setter methods for it.  poof it's done.

TYVM!

Comment: BTW: "commercial_name" should be "commercialName".

Comment: @Philippe: It's a universal convention. Many Cocoa features actually depend on things being named that way.

Comment: Says Apple. Check the conventions for ivar naming and method naming: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF . A number of builtin things like KVC and KVO actually depend on the name conforming, and if they don't you have to write extra code to deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd check out Accessorizer: http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html

Comment: that's what i meant in my answer ,)

Answer (score 4):

On the iPhone, which uses the "modern runtime", you can ommit the ivar (field declaration). Simply declaring and synthesizing the property is enough. The ivar is created at runtime.

More info here (at the end of the page):

https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

Another discussion:

[Using instance variables with Modern Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007607/using-instance-variables-with-modern-runtime)

Sadly, this mechanism doesn't work in the iPhone simulator, not even in Snow Leopard :-(

Comment: The new Objective-C runtime is 64-bit only, and it looks like the iPhone Simulator isn't yet 64-bit on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

there are autocompletion scripts (like typing 'log' and then pressing Cmd + . to autocomplete this to NSLog())

you could build one that would insert these three lines and you'd need to provide only the name and type for the property.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link, he has written an Apple Script which you can use in XCode and he has put the video as-well for us to see how to use it properly!

http://allancraig.net/blog/?p=315

Comment: Also check out some great tools for lazy Objective C programmers like me lox

http://github.com/holtwick/xobjc/tree/master