# Is there a way to make dynamic ivars show up in XCode 4's GUI debugger?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I like the convenience of skipping explicit declaration of ivars, and just using @property/@synthesize.

But ivars done this way don't show up in the Debug Area variables list in XCode 4 (at least with gdb/iOS; don't know about lldb).

Is there any way of forcing them to do so?

*Notes:*

1. I know I can get the ivar values using gdb commands in the console, or breakpoint actions
2. There are a couple of similar questions here (eg. [xcode 3.2.2 and objective-c 2.0 and debug: where are my object's property/instance variable values in debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970399/xcode-3-2-2-and-objective-c-2-0-and-debug-where-are-my-objects-property-instanc)) but I am specifically looking for an XCode 4 workaround.

Answer (score 1):

We are all in the same boat, unfortunately.  Maybe LLDB will fix this to some degree, although we are waiting for Apple to add it back in as an option.  This is probably my biggest gripe with Xcode.

Comment: For the moment I'm just staying with use of explicitly-declared vars. It seems to save time. (As for gripes with XCode, I have a few ...)