# UIWIndow Not Declared iOS 4.3 AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I just downloaded the newest iOS SDK (4.3) and noticed that when I start a Window Based Application, the UIWindow is not declared in the header file, it is only mentioned as a property.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GleekAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

I would expect, and remember from older SDK's, that the above code should be

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GleekAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;

    UIWindow *window;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Is that just a new feature of the SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Objective-C runtime has the ability to synthesize ivars without explicitly declaring them. From [Runtime Difference in The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW3):

> In general the behavior of properties
>   is identical on both modern and legacy
>   runtimes (see “Runtime Versions and
>   Platforms” in Objective-C Runtime
>   Programming Guide). There is one key
>   difference: the modern runtime
>   supports instance variable synthesis
>   whereas the legacy runtime does not.

...

> With the modern runtime, if you do not
>   provide an instance variable, the
>   compiler adds one for you.

From [Runtime Versions and Platforms in Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH106):

> - Phone applications and 64-bit programs on Mac OS X v10.5 and later
>     use the modern version of the runtime.
> - Other programs (32-bit programs on Mac OS X desktop) use the legacy
>     version of the runtime.

Also have a look at this questions:

- [Objective C: Why do we declare ivars in the .h member area if @property seems to do it automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555736/objective-c-why-do-we-declare-ivars-in-the-h-member-area-if-property-seems-to)
- [What is the underlying mechanism for ivar synthesis in the modern Objective C runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275034/what-is-the-underlying-mechanism-for-ivar-synthesis-in-the-modern-objective-c-run)
- [Automatic iVars with @synthesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343475/automatic-ivars-with-synthesize)